# How do I turn the diagonal line to the other side?

Tags: java, diagonal

I have this code but it's printing the diagonal like this...I wanted to go from top right to bottom left, any idea how to turn it?

```
*
 *
  *
   *
    *
```

Code:

```
class Diagonal {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int row, col;

        String spaces = " ";

        for( row = 1; row < 6; row++) {
            System.out.println(spaces +"*");
            spaces += " ";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: C# equivalent: `Enumerable.Range(5,0).Select(x => new string(' ',x) + "*").ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);` - Single line of code.

Comment: @HighCore: I don't think it's productive to cite what you could do in another language.  Java streams and closures are coming in Java 8, but since they're not here yet, how you would do it in C# is irrelevant.

Comment: If you wanted to use closures, you might as well do it in Scala, which at least is directly interoperable with Java.

Comment: @NathanielFord Scala sounds promising, can you show me the equivalent in Scala to my line?

Answer (score 2):

You construct your diagonal by inserting a space for each additional row. Therefore, if you start with some number of rows and remove a space you should get an inversion. But we need to clean up how we're doing spaces so that we can subtract the number per row more easily.

```
class Diagonal{
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    int row, col;
    for( row = 6; row > 0; row--) {
      for (int x = 0; x < row; x++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
      }
      System.out.print("*\n");//note carriage return
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I try doing that but it gives me an infinite diagonal

Comment: Haha! Yes, parameters are important. :) The outer for loop must go from 6 down to 0.